# How to handle a questions which does not seem to be a question

Tags: discussion

This question [Summary: Take a picture utilizing Camera Intent and display the photo with correct orientation (works on hopefully all devices)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019165/summary-take-a-picture-utilizing-camera-intent-and-display-the-photo-with-corre) looks like a project someone wants to share with the community in a forum style.
Already the first revision stated:
*I hope this is helpful to some of you. Moreover, if you have suggestions for improvements please let everybody know. And again, this is mainly a compiliation of the work of others. So many many thanks to them!*

The answers on this "question", meanwhile contaning an updated answer by the TO, are also a mix of stating problems and attempted solutions.
I have no idea how to make this fit for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that this isn't a question, doesn't describe a problem, and the answer isn't "answering" anything, but rather responding to comments (and also, it seems, as a way for him to be given a bounty for information in the question), it sounds like the whole thing would just be better off posted as a blog post rather than being on a Q/A site.  While yes, it may be technically possible to write a question and answer pair that would include all of this information, doing so would be a huge amount of work; work that isn't really adding value.  The information simply isn't designed to be a Q/A, which is fine, tutorials are great, they just aren't what this site exists for.

Comment: So it should be closed with an off topic "Other" reason and the owner could decide to create a new self answered  question?

Comment: @bummi That's my inclination, yes.  If the author (or someone else) *really* wants it to belong on this site, it could be refactored into an actual question with an answer, as opposed to an answer posted as a question with a comment posted as an answer.  It would likely be quite a bit of work, but it could all be done through editing.  As I said, I don't see that editing as being productive, and I think it would be better served posted as a blog post, but if someone wants to take the time to make it a real question, that's fine.

Comment: Off Topic/Unclear what you're asking seems right to me.

Comment: @Joe Yeah, I could possibly see it, but I think this case is unusual enough to warrant a custom reason.  Even if one of those reasons technically applied, it'd still cause confusion.  Although "too broad", as mentioned by another person, does apply fairly well...

Comment: Hi guys, I originally created the above mentioned post and updated it over time. Initially, the question stated some issues which I was not able to resolve on my own at the time. Moreover, I figured people struggeling with the same issues would find my solution on StackOverflow much easier than on any private blog post. Over the christmas holidays, I'll open a public repository on github. Please let me know how you would like me to resolve the issue and I'm happy to put in the extra work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I separated the question part from the answer part. Please consider to reopen the thread. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: @Ralf It looks like a textbook "too broad" question to me now.  It gives an entire topic and just asks, "How do I do it right?"  That's not a specific question at all, nor does it have a specific answer.

Comment: @Servy I understand that it seems to be a broad question but the issue with the camera intent is that there are many posts on how to do it on a specifc devices. Implementing it across all devices out there is not covered so far and I suppose my code was already helpful to some developers. Moreover, the post summarizes several solutions posted on StackOverflow in a single post. Frankly, I don't know how to be more specifc but I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: @Ralf That's the point, and why I didn't try to spend a lot of time trying to fix it; the inherent goal that you're trying to accomplish is simply very broad.  Making it specific would defeat the purpose of what you're trying to do.  It simply doesn't fit very well into SE's question model, hence my suggestion that you provide the information through another means, i.e. a blog.